# Entering Netherlands on Schengen and then find a job on dependent visa

Tags: resident-permit, netherlands, schengen

I'm moving on my wife's dependent visa (MVV) to NL. Can I apply for a Schengen and enter through that visa while I find a job and then exit and enter on the MVV visa.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? A dependent visa (National visa, type D) can be used, outside of the issuing country, as a Schengen Visa (type C).

Comment: @MarkJohnson perhaps to search for a job before the MVV is valid; that is, to reduce the time between the arrival on the MVV and the beginning of an income stream.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, job searching is permissible with a regular Schengen visa (as long as you don't work before you are authorized, of course).

As Mark Johnson's comment implies, there's no reason to do this other than to get an early start on your job search before your MVV is issued, before you're prepared to actually make the move.  If that isn't your reason, there's no point in delaying the MVV.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I should have clarified a bit more. My intention was to get benefit of the 30% ruling. So two follow ups
(a) Can I have 2 visa (Schengen and MVV) at the same time. My MVV is under process through my wife's employer and I plan to apply for Schengen on my own.
(b) Can I enter NL on Schengen while I have MVV as well. 
Idea is to find a job and then exit (150kms away) and re-enter on MVV and be eligible for 30% ruling.

Comment: How would that make you eligible for the 30% ruling?

Comment: my understanding was that as long as you enter NL with a job offer, you are eligible for 30% ruling. please do advise as I'm still getting to know the nitty-gritties of the tax regulations.